# how to convert speech from Text-to-speech application into mp3 file?

Tags: android, performance, text-to-speech

I am developing a text-to-speech android application. I wish to convert my translated speech into a mp3 file and save it on the device. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) :

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
String destFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";
myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, wakeUpText);
mTts.synthesizeToFile(wakeUpText, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

**OR**

[THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971009/1576416)

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I am still having some problem with my code. It would be great if you help me.  I am inserting your code in the SpeakText method and changing the variable names,etc. But, it is not working. Can you tell me where am I going wrong? `code`    public void speakText(View view){
     String toSpeak = write.getText().toString();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      
   }
} `code`

Comment: check WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is you must put that code in a right place, also never forget to add this permission to the manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">


 </uses-permission>
```

or i give you a [link](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/07/convert-text-to-speech-into-audio.html) on this stuff...