# Pandorabot Speech Interfaces

Tags: android, speech, chatbot, pandorabots

I want to create a application android that use pandorabot with Speech Interfaces like CallMOM

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pandorabots.callmom

Is there any example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is pretty simple:

1. recognize user input
2. send it to pandorabots
3. get result back
4. synthesize it with TTS engine
5. go to step 1

You can learn more about speech recognition on Android from answer on [Is there a way to use the SpeechRecognizer API directly for speech input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975443/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-speechrecognizer-api-directly-for-speech-input)

You can learn more about TTS on Android from answer on [Android TTS speech synthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967498/android-tts-speech-synthesizer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/The-Kunze/Pandorabots-Android-App) that should give you the basics idea of building an Android app that talks to the [Pandorabots API](https://chatbots.io).